# Pyside - QFileDialog Initial Lag

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyside, qfiledialog

Could anyone confirm that QFileDialog have a initial lag? It takes about 15~30 seconds to start the application, when I comment out it takes none.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class MainFrame(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.file_dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainFrame()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Python 2.7.6
Pyside 1.2.2
Qt 5.3

Running on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits

I found this two website [(first)](http://www.qtfr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2236)(it's in french), [(second)](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-13182)(a bug report on pyside website), and both confirm that QFileDialog does have some lag issues.

Is there a way to fix or circumvent this problem?

Comment: Are you saying that you get the lag without even showing the dialog? Have you tried setting the [DontUseCustomDirectoryIcons](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#Option-enum) option?

Comment: Yes, the lag occurs in the  `self.file_dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog(self)` line. I guess it won't matter if I set to DontUseCustomDirectoryIcons, because to use it I need a QFileDialog, and since the lag happens when creating it.

Comment: Does it really happen when creating it, or only when the event loop starts? Try creating a button to open the dialog once the main window is open, rather than trying to create it during `__init__` (which is a bit articial). Also: do you have any network or usb drives in your setup?

Comment: What do you mean by `when the event loop starts`? My code is just that and it freezes, i'm not trying to open the QFileDialog, I just instantiated it. If I move the instantiation of the QFileDialog widget to a button connected to a function it will lag when I clicked that button.

Comment: The event loop is started by `app.exec_()`. Any code that is executed before then will post events to the event queue, and it could be one of those events that causes the lag. This could have a bearing on where to look in the source code of QFileDialog to see what might be causing the lag. One possibility is that it is trying to set the working directory, which might entail accessing the filesystem (this is why I asked you whether you had any network or usb drives in your setup). Do you have another Windows box where you can test the same code?

Comment: I tried commenting out the app.exec_() bit, if the lag was in the instantiation of the widget it would freeze for a second before closing, right? Well, it didn't, so it might be true that QFileDialog is queuing something and lagging the app when it starts. Is there a way to unqueue anything that it might have? Or perhaps move some of those items in the queue to another thread?

Comment: An easier way to test is to put some print statements before and after `main = MainFrame()` - commenting out the other lines is not helpful. Also: can you please answer the other questions I asked?

Comment: Ah, sorry. No I don't have any other machine.

Comment: Using Python 3.4, PySide 1.2.2 (uses Qt 4.8 not 5.3) and Windows 7 (all 64 bit) I don't see any lag.